# Why to use the sign convention while solving problems as the mirror-formula itself is derived using the sign convention?

Tags: geometric-optics

When we derive the mirror equation of concave mirror, i.e.,$\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}=\frac{1}{f},$ we've already used the sign conventions. Then why to use the sign conventions again while solving a problem?

Say the object is at $5~\text{cm}$ from pole.Then we take $u$ as $-5.$ We've used signs while deriving the formula and yet again while solving the problem. In that case I think that we are not at all using the sign convention.